# Django - Generic Foreign Key or Query in forms.py?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, generic-foreign-key

I have been piecing together a model for the best part of today using ContentType/Generic Foreign Key as, from my Googling, it seemed to be the solution I was looking for. However, now that I have something rendering, it doesn't seem to be the case.

All I want is a foreign key dropdown that allows the user to select a record from One of Two models. With a GenericForeignKey it lists the models specified in my 'limit' statement but then expects the user to know the ID/PK and enter it in the 'object_id' field. Is this correct?

I am now thinking a query to get all records from both models and list them in a dropdown would be a much cleaner solution. If so, would I just achieve this in forms.py?

The foreign key element isnt too important as I only need to be able to import/manipulate some fields from the Two associated models and save them to the new model.

Thanks in advance.